# What do you call it when someone assumes a newly created position?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I am the first person in a position and wanted to know what to call myself. I thought about "first incumbent," but it doesn't feel right. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A word is [*inaugural*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inaugural)

> marking the beginning of a new venture, series, etc.
>   *the inaugural run of the pony express.*

So if you're the first chairman of a new organization, you would call yourself the *inaugural chairman of ...*.

Comment: Thanks Bamar. What do you think of the phrase "inaugural incumbent"?

Comment: `The inaugural Chief of Privacy of Facebook, Mr. Barmar, refuses to carry a smartphone` Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. It would be something like "inaugural chairman" to mean the first chairman.

Comment: @JohnsontheFirst - One is considered the incumbent only when speaking in the context of the person who has been (or is in the process of being) selected to replace them.   The use of *incumbent* has the subtext that they are “on their way out the door” so you don’t want to be known as the incumbent when you’ve just taken the position.

Comment: @Jim I don't think it means "out the door", that's a lame duck. An incumbent is the current holder during a campaign to choose a new holder of the position, and often the incumbent is the favorite to win re-election.

Comment: @Barmar - You’re right about possibility of being re-elected. I stand corrected.  But I think it’s still only used in the context of referencing the upcoming office holder.

Comment: Yes, the latter is true. An incumbent is the current office-holder who is running for re-election.